# syncronization from active directory to azure

Tags: active-directory, synchronization, office365

I have created an user but with some errors, error on smtp: SMTP SIP etc... I changed it on Active Directory OU sync to azure but the values set after creation on office 365 and exchange is still the same (the .onmicrosoft.com alias wasn't create at the beginning and now this value doesn't want to change) I try to sync with PowerShell command : Start-ADSyncSyncCycle -PolicyType Delta , and I check on synchronization manager and I still have the same value

Comment: Please rephrase your question. As it is, we don't understand what your problem is or what you're asking.

Comment: please ask me what you don't understand… for sum up sync from ad azure to  exchange 365 fail for aliases (smtp:,SIP:, SMTP)